# How to copy a link to socialshare-url using ng-model in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
 <input type="url" id="linkid" style="border:1px solid black;padding:0.5%" ng-model="shareLink">
 
 <a target="_self" socialshare socialshare-provider="facebook" socialshare-text="720kb AngularJS Socialshare" socialshare-hashtags="angularjs, angular-socialshare" socialshare-url="shareLink">
```

I want to copy a link to socialshare-url for sharing that link in social sites that was generated when a button is clicked.Iam trying to copy the link using ng-model but it was not working.How can I copy a link to social

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On ng-change of the input call a function to update the attribute of the anchor link. Then in your angular controller assign the input model to that anchor element.

In the html:

```
<input ng-model="shareLink" ng-change="updateLink()">
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.updateLink = function()
        {
            document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("socialshare-url", $scope.shareLink);
        }
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AKMorris/cm4jbo6p/